# Joomla Error on local system while same package works fine on Hosting service

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7, joomla-template

I have installed xampp package.
I am trying to run Joomla application over xampp.

But I am not sure wats wrong with the application but I am getting this error.
Exactly the same Joomla package and Theme works fine on my hosting but locally it giving me below error. Not sure if there something wrong at system level because the same package works fine on hosting service. I have WIndows 7 32 bit.

Any idea anyone ? Thanks in advance

===============================================================================

Strict Standards: Non-static method modSlideShowSP2Helper::getImages() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\travel\modules\mod_slideshow_pro_sp2\helper.php on line 124

Strict Standards: Non-static method modSlideShowSP2Helper::getImages() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\travel\modules\mod_slideshow_pro_sp2\helper.php on line 125

Strict Standards: Non-static method modSlideShowSP2Helper::cText() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\travel\modules\mod_slideshow_pro_sp2\helper.php on line 127

Strict Standards: Non-static method modSlideShowSP2Helper::cText() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\travel\modules\mod_slideshow_pro_sp2\helper.php on line 128

Strict Standards: Non-static method modSlideShowSP2Helper::cText() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\travel\modules\mod_slideshow_pro_sp2\helper.php on line 129

Strict Standards: Non-static method modSlideShowSP2Helper::cText() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\travel\modules\mod_slideshow_pro_sp2\helper.php on line 130

Strict Standards: Non-static method modSlideShowSP2Helper::getImages() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\travel\modules\mod_slideshow_pro_sp2\helper.php on line 124

=====================================================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all extensions for Joomla are developed under strict standards. `error_reporting(0)` at the top of your entry script (index.php) should fix the problem. If you use this directive, however, you won't be able to trace errors on the production server.
An alternative would be:

```
//have all errors trapped, but not displayed
error_reporting(- 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is editing your php.ini file.
Find row like this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

and delete E_STRICT with vertical line. Then restart xampp.